# Opening sharepoint documents from Silverlight and re-use session

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, isaserver

We have a silverlight application thats behind a ISA server, and the users have to authenticate against the ISA server.

In the silverlight application we uses Sharepoint 2007 as a documentlibrary (the backend uploads the documents).

When the user wants to open a document, we use a javascript, **editDocumentWithProgID2**, and HtmlPage.Window.Invoke(...) in silverlight.

The problem is that word/excel shows a new login dialog, so the users have to login again. Is there a way of avoiding this login dialog?

cheers
Thomas

Comment: I'm putting my money that you can't. This is how the Windows authentication works. I'm not certain though.

Answer (score 0):

Word/Excel act like a second "browser", you can't reuse the session. 
The only way to avoid double login is to save the file on the local drive and then open it with office.

Comment: yes, but the problem is that the users is supposed to save the document back to the sharepoint document library...